# How do I scan with zxing in landscape mode and locked?

Tags: c#, xamarin, zxing

```
var result = await _scanner.Scan(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
{
    AutoRotate = false,
    TryHarder = true,
    PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> {
        BarcodeFormat.CODE_39
    }
});
```

This makes orientation stay in portrait because it starts in portrait.
How do I make it start in landscape?

Comment: You dont mention if you are using Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IOs or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Android, C#, and just calling this from MainActivity. OnCreate()

Comment: An option would be to force your activity to only be available in landscape?

Comment: Something like this `[Activity(ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]`.  If you already have an activity attribute, just att the `ScreenOrientation = ...` bit

Comment: No I already have MainAcitvity attributes set to portrait exactly like that, but when scan starts, its in portrait, and if
                         AutoRotate = false
then i stays in portrait. I need it to start in landscape and lock in landscape and have button to change

Comment: I meant, change that to `Landscape`... sorry

Comment: Yep activity is locked but when I hit scan, it immediately goes to portrait